# how can i change my geometry in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, arcgis

i need to change the geometry `MDSYS.SDO_Geometry` to `SDE.ST_Geometry` because that's required for migration `(ArcGis 9.3 to Arcgis 10.5)` and those geometries are not compatible.

I tried to see how they built it but i don't understand how can i make it. I have the code for both of them if someone can help me.

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2002,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),
    MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-72.1047299999991,-41.4399799999992,-72.1057099999998,-41.4404200000008,-72.1062500000007,-41.4405299999999,-72.1072399999994,-41.4404900000009,-72.1090899999999,-41.4401600000001,-72.1096799999996,-41.4399900000008,-72.1102499999997,-41.4395100000002,-72.11064999878,-41.4390500012214,-72.1106899999995,-41.4390100000001))


SDE.ST_GEOMETRY(4,21,-69.5,-19.76245,-69.49831,-19.75843,0,0,NULL,NULL,0,0.00665337290908277,300003,'oracle.sql.BLOB@4f5a1e8d')
```

[what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnIBY.jpg)

Comment: A quick internet search for `ArcGis 9.3 to Arcgis 10.5 migration oracle` leads to this [ArcGis page on Data Migration](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/data-migration.htm) that suggests there is a tool available to perform this migration.

Comment: Very very thanks for the answer, thats works!

Comment: You can write up your own answer detailing the steps you took to perform the migration as it might be useful to other people.

Comment: Ok, in a few minuts, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally and thanks for the cooperation from [MT10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0) i make the migration of data whit the tool "Migrate Storage".

[Migration Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDsVf.png)

Just need a SDE connection and insert the data to convert. Just follow the instructions in the follow link: [data-migration](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/data-migration.htm)

Before you migrate...
The following conditions must be met before you convert your data:

- You must make a backup of the data before you migrate it.
- If you are converting the spatial column data type, the data must be stored in high precision. If your data is currently stored with basic precision, you must first migrate it to high precision before you migrate the storage type. Use the Upgrade Spatial Reference geoprocessing tool to upgrade to high precision.
- If you are converting the spatial column data type, the data must be stored in high precision. If your data is currently stored with basic precision, you must first migrate it to high precision before you migrate the storage type. Use the Upgrade Spatial Reference geoprocessing tool to upgrade to high precision.
- The table or feature class must be registered with the geodatabase.
- The configuration keyword you specify when migrating the data type has to contain the correct value for the GEOMETRY_STORAGE, ATTRIBUTE_BINARY, or RASTER_STORAGE parameter. For example, if you want to migrate a LONG RAW geometry column to ST_GEOMETRY, but you specify a keyword that has the GEOMETRY_STORAGE parameter set to SDO_GEOMETRY, the migration will fail because that is not a supported migration path.
- You must be logged in as the owner of the table that contains the column being migrated.
  Migration of a feature class to the SQL Server GEOGRAPHY type requires that the data be in one of the geographic coordinate systems supported by the GEOGRAPHY type.

> Tip: The list of supported coordinate systems that can be used with
>   the SQL Server GEOGRAPHY type is in the SQL Server system view
>   sys.spatial_reference_systems. If your geodatabase is in SQL Server
>   2008 or 2008 R2, feature classes migrated to the SQL Server GEOGRAPHY
>   type cannot contain z- or m-coordinate values.